# How to have Safari open links with the evil target attribute open in the same tab?

Tags: safari, ui, web-browsing, web-browser, websites

In some pages, there are (still) links marked `target="_blank"`.

Safari opens such link in a new tab.

How to have Safari open such link in the same tab ?

I have Safari 7 on Mavericks. I have older Safari as well.

Comment: Noo, don’t do that ! These curly quotes in my question are totally wrong ! This sort of “correction” smells of Microsoft Word. I have written correctly target="_blank".

Comment: I have tried \``the backtick trick`\` — to no avail.

Comment: Now I have edited the title, to circumvent the auto-“correction”. The site wrongly transforms target="_blank" into target=“_blank”, à la Microsoft. Incredible, but true.

Answer (score 3):

Install the Safari extension [LinkThing](http://canisbos.com/linkthing) to customize links behavior. It should be able to solve your problem, additionally, you can also customize the onsite and offsite links behavior.

Comment: I have adopted the extension LinkThing ! A nice one, despite the weird way to go in its prefs. However, it does not work with JavaScript off, and it fails to work on some link(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a userscript such as the following:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    if (a[i].getAttribute('target')=='_blank')
        a[i].setAttribute('target','_self');
```

[Install](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/x6deyu64hgn9cid/blanktoself.user.js)

I recommend installing using [NinjaKit](https://github.com/os0x/NinjaKit) for Safari, but other userscript extensions also work.

Comment: What do you call a “userscript” ? Thank you, but this looks complicated.

Comment: It's basically a JavaScript script that runs on pages specified in the `@include` line (`*` = all pages). You can install it using one of many 'Greasemonkey' extensions, and I recommend [NinjaKit](https://github.com/os0x/NinjaKit). Simply download and install the [Safari extension](http://ss-o.net/safari/extension/NinjaKit.safariextz), then click the install link in my answer. The script I've written above will get all `a` links on the page, and if their attribute is `_blank` it will change it to `_self`.

Comment: @Nicolas Why not?

Comment: For several reasons. The main reason is : I don’t want a mill running in all the links of all the pages ! :-)

Comment: @Nicolas If it's only certain domains that you want the script to run on (like I did for my remote intranet), you can limit the script to only run on that domain by changing the `@include` line or lines to one or more domains.